# System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. A string with spaces

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I believe I've isolated where the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my source:

```
for (int i = client.GetMessageCount(); i > 0 && iEmailCredit > 0; i--)
{
    OpenPop.Mime.Message unseenMessage = client.GetMessage(i);
    string sFrom = unseenMessage.Headers.From.Address.ToString().ToLower();
    string sName = unseenMessage.Headers.From.DisplayName.ToString().ToLower();
    (...)
}
```

Here's the full exeception:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
at OpenPop.Mime.Decode.Base64.Decode(String base64Encoded)
at OpenPop.Mime.Decode.Base64.Decode(String base64Encoded, Encoding encoding)
at OpenPop.Mime.Decode.EncodedWord.Decode(String encodedWords)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.RfcMailAddress.ParseMailAddress(String input)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeader(String headerName, String headerValue)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeaders(NameValueCollection headers)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader..ctor(NameValueCollection headers)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderExtractor.ExtractHeadersAndBody(Byte[] fullRawMessage, MessageHeader& headers, Byte[]& body)
at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent, Boolean parseBody)
at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent)
at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage(Int32 messageNumber)
at ProcessProject.frmInboxLock.FetchUnseenMessages(String sAspNetUserId, String username, String password, String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean useSsl, Int32 iEmailCredit, String WhiteList, String BlackList) in c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ServiceProject\ProcessProject\Process.cs:line 277
at ProcessProject.frmInboxLock.FiveMinuteTrigger_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ServiceProject\ProcessProject\Process.cs:line 618
```

It says that error occurs on the line with " OpenPop.Mime.Message = client..." but I believe when I remove the "string sName" line it stops throwing errors. I'm pretty sure it may be because of the spaces in the display name such as "John Doe". I'm also running an application, not a web page. Please help, thanks, Chris.

Comment: Can you not use the debugger to determine the line? what is `client.GetMessage(i)` doing?

Comment: client.Getmessage is an openpop function that receives the listed email off of a particular persons email account. I'm told that it's this line: OpenPop.Mime.Message unseenMessage = client.GetMessage(i);. But, I've seen the debugger be off a few line before and this didn't start happening until I added the line with sName

Comment: Please write the exception's stack trace. Obviously the failure occurs at a deeper level than the code you're showing.

Comment: Line 618 is just the line in my code that calls the function where the error occurs at 277. 277 is the "OpenPop.Mime.Message unseenMessage = client.GetMessage(i);" line.

Comment: It's unlikely that the addition of the line that gets the name is what triggers this problem. It appears that the message itself is corrupt.

Comment: @JimMischel is right, you're not investigating at the right place here. Look into server's response for GetMessage method. This is where lies the true problem.

Comment: Well, obviously somewhere in the course of the `GetMessage` function a string should be decoded from base64, but it is not a valid base64 string. That's what the error says. A base64 string can not contain spaces or anything but 0..9A..F.